# get_template_part() doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, get-template-part

I use get_template_part() function to get theme options page content like this:

```
function setup_theme_admin_menus() {
    add_theme_page( "Theme Options", "Theme Options", "read", "theme_options", "theme_options" );
}
function theme_options() {
    get_template_part("content","options");
}
```

And it seems to work perfect when I use it on my localhost but when I relocated it online it stopped rendering desired HTML. When I use something like:

```
function theme_options() {
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

It works as expected both online and locally. No idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The [`get_template_part()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is intended to include a *template-part* file in the *template* - i.e. on the *front end*.

Use `include()` instead, along with [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory):

```
function theme_options() {
    include( get_template_directory() . '/content-options.php' );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure now what my problem is. Your structure doesn't work either. I tried even putting something like *include("http://fullurl.com/wp-content/themes/theme/content-options.php");* and it doesn't work too. But when I echo something it generates content as expected ... WTF!?!?

Comment: It seems like I have a corrupted content-options.php file! Sorry for bothering ... how to erase my question form the history? The amount of shame on me right now is unbearable!!